# CSS\HTML - How to add Ionicons to CSS "content" property?

Tags: html, css, ionicons

I'm using a custom `switch` toggle (from [here](https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/)) and I want to add an icon instead of regular text. When I paste the `Ionicons` code to the CSS `content` property it appears as a rectangle (some indication for the fact the character\font was not found). How do I get pass this?

EDIT:
I forgot to add, I have included the CSS from CDN.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hg369n1c/)

Switch CSS:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; 
    width: 108px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; 
    -moz-user-select:none; 
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; 
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; 
    width: 200%; 
    margin-left: -100%;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; 
    float: left; width: 50%; 
    height: 40px; padding: 0; 
    line-height: 38px;
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    color: #BABABA;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "\f425"; /* <--------THE ICON GOES HERE */
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #8035A7; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; 
    width: 41px; margin: -1.5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #999999; 
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 66px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
            <p id="impressions_meter_text">Impressions meter</p>
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: looking at the source code of `node_modules\ionicons\dist\scss` sadly it appears the developers did a real bad work here and used zero SCSS functions and mixins to allow what you ask to do

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're missing a `@font-face` declaration that imports the "Ionicons" font face, plus the `.onoffswitch-inner:after` declaration doesn't specify the `font-family: "Ionicons";`.

I've extracted the Ionicons font declaration from their css and added it to [a forked jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rs8p81h6/).

Answer (score 7):

You ommit the font-family property .. when you use a code from a font icon into CSS content property you must do it like this :

```
.custom-icon:after {
    content: "\f425";
    font-family: "the name of the font icon you are using";
}
```

And that's it :P

Comment: That's the worst thing to do. this will break if some icon will be removed and the corresponding *unicode* value will be different.

Answer (score 6):

**Using Ionic V2**

to use ionicons from : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/ionicons/ in your css, you just need to do like that.

```
.yourclass {
        font-family: "Ionicons";
        content: "\f3d1";
}
```

**this will print:** `<ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>`

you can find the content hexadecimal in:

```
node_modules/ionic-angular/css/ionic.css:

node_modules/ionic-angular/css/ionic.dark.css
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to import ion icon css files to load the icon font. Please, read the doc at https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons

1. Download and extract the font pack
2. Copy the ionicons.css to your project
3. Copy the fonts folder to your project
4. Ensure the font urls within ionicons.css properly reference the fonts path within your project.
5. Include a reference to the ionicons.css file from every webpage you need to use it.

Then, instead of put "content" directly, you could use the classes that framework provide us, as:

`<i class="icon ion-home"></i>`

Comment: That wasn't the question.

Comment: You are wrong Adam, if you don't import the css font you never could load the icon, so in the example that user provide us the icon font not exist.

Comment: The OP didn't ask how to use an `i` tag - the OP asked how come the font wasn't displaying when the character was included in a `content` rule - which was because 1) The font wasn't included (as stated in your post) and 2) because the OP didn't declare the `font-family`